# How to cleanly fill in space between 2 objects after solidify?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, objects

Apologies if this type of situation was already encountered by someone else. Just could not find a solution for the life of me. Also please keep in mind that I am brand new to blender, so the more detailed explanation the better.

Essentially, I've created a model that has a head and hair, both separate objects from each other (probably not good practice). I tried using solidify on the hair to fill in the gap between the inside faces of the hair and the outside faces of the head, so that they meet up and don't leave any voids. Reason for doing this is I'm trying to 3D print it, and when I run the model through my slicer, I can see that those spaces are completely empty and actually have supports printing in order to make up the space, which I don't want.

Is there anything I can do at this stage of the model that would fix this problem? Or do I have to start from scratch and try a different approach? Obviously, I'd rather the former, but if I just truly botched this thing then I'm not entirely opposed to starting again and doing it the "right" way.

The only thing I can think is that I should've made the hair into an object with depth instead of a single plane of faces? But I don't really know how I would even approach doing that and still getting the look that I wanted.

[image: Modeled head]

This is the modeled head

[image: Area between hair and head that I'd like to fill in (turned off solidify for a clearer image)]

The highlighted edge is the area between hair and head that I'd like to fill in (turned off solidify for a clearer image).

Edit: Figured out how to post the link.
[Modeled Head with Issues](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j3o1whqa7u33i00/TGL_Head_Issues.blend?dl=0)

Comment: Hmm I cannot see clearly your hair from other side but does your hair have similar or same edge count around as top of the head? If yes you could just duplicate top of the head, separate it to different object, then join it with head and select all edges of hair and all edges of head, use RMB and select Bridge edge loops (if you have same edge count it will create nice topo to work with, if not you will have to tweak it a bit... Is there a way to see your file? I could show what I mean

Comment: @MikoCG, I used Shift+D on the top of the head to create the faces for the hair, then P to make it a separate object and modified from there... Which sounds like what you just described. I've tried joining the hair to the head but I think the mirror modifier is making it go crazy bc it never looks right. I actually couldn't find a way to upload the file for you guys to see

Comment: @MikoCG, file is now up for viewing

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the *Solidify* (or extrude *Faces Along Normals* instead) then boolean the object with the head, but you need to make sure that the topology is correct (i.e. no overlapping faces).

The other solution would be to draw the hair line on the surface of the head (with the knife for example) and extrude:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The latter sounds like what I should've done in the first place lol. Would that effect how the colors get applied?

Comment: you can assign different materials to different faces, but I thought it was mainly for 3D print? Also maybe try the boolean to see if it works?

Comment: it is for 3D printing, I was just curious for presentation purposes. I will try once I'm home tonight. Worst case, I start again using the knife/extrude method. Thanks again

Comment: so I tried the boolean and after fixing the overlapping faces, it appeared to join the parts...but it still didn't fill in the space between the hair and head. It actually looked like it made its own copy of the head that was joined to the hair, which was odd.

I tried joining the true head with this weird hybrid and slicing it, but the results are worse than before. Looks like I'll have to go back and knife/extrude

Comment: hello, maybe share your file so that we can give a try, remember that once you've booleaned, you need to delete the boolean object: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: File is now up for viewing. I've never used blender before creating this model, so please forgive me for not knowing basic things

Comment: your mehes need to be clean (no overlapping faces, closed volumes i.e. no holes), your hair need to penetrate inside the head (which is not the case for the moment), apply the mirror and solidify modifiers of the objects (not the subdivision surface), then try the boolean, but I'm not sur it will work as your meshes are a bit messy, so maybe my method is surer  ;)   the solidify itself make things difficult as faces are overlapping